# Every time login firebase got error the user does not have a password in ionic 3?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, ionic3

I have to login with firebse but after enter email and password I got error in the console every time "the password is invalid or the user does not have a password"

But my UID is generated properly in firebase. I don't understand why every time I get an error Anyone know how to fix this issue?

```js
//createUserAccount after click on button
createUserAccount(event){
  //Get the input value assign into object format and pass in the API
  let object = {
    "email"             : this.createAccountForm.value.email,
    "password"          : this.createAccountForm.value.newPassword
  }
    //Call the signupUserFB function for get the add the user into the firebase 
    self.authData.signupUserFB(function(isSuccess, newUser){
      console.log("signupUserFB isSuccess: " + isSuccess);
  }, object);
}

//singInUserInFb for store user in FB
singInUserInFb(callback: any, object : any): any {
  var self = this;

  //Enable the loader after call the FB function
  var loading = self.loadingCtrl.create({
    content: "Loading..."
  });
  loading.present();

//passing the email & password.
  this.fireAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(object.email, object.password).then((authData) => {
    console.log(authData.uid);

  });
}
```